# Joining the same table twice in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that I want to join. Let's call them A, B, C. I would like to have the same result of these two queries but only with one:

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON B.ext_id = A._id
SELECT * FROM A JOIN C ON C.ext_id = A._id
```

Also, B.ext_id and C.ext_id  can't have the same value, meaning that the same value of A._id can't be in both B.ext_id and C.ext_id

Obviously this query:

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON B.ext_id = A._id JOIN C ON C.ext_id = A._id
```

Returns null.
What should I do? Thanks

Comment: can u please add some example data and show your expected resultset from that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical method uses `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(b.col1, c.col1) as col1
from a left join
     b
     on b.ext_id = a._id left join
     c
     on c.ext_id = a._id;
```

Use the `coalesce()` for all columns that you want from the two tables.

Comment: I guess Inner Join is working properly in case of 2 tables. Also, OP only wants column from Table A.

Comment: What if I have more then 2 tables and I still want to join them with table A? Does this still work?

Comment: @Deci . . . Yes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I wasn't paying too much attention and I selected the first one that seemed your answer

Comment: Oh, sorry, it must have been a typo yesterday when I was reviewing my old questions.

Answer (score 0):

This query will provide you with what you are looking for and not show any non-matches, similar to the two inner join queries you were executing. This should work for additional tables as well.

```
SELECT a.*, COALESCE(b.ext_id, c.ext_id) AS ext_id
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON A._id = B.ext_id
    LEFT JOIN C ON A._id = C.ext_id
WHERE COALESCE(b.ext_id, c.ext_id) IS NOT NULL
```